# Can I have partially overlapping columns in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns in Bootstrap 3, one with a couple of images in it, the other with one big image. I want one column - the one with multiple images - to be partially overlapped the other, so one image overlaps the three other images. If I try this the big image gets moved either down or up. Is the a way to overlap these columns? it is impossible to put both images in the same column, due to the rest of the page.

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-2">
  <!-- three images -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <!-- bit image -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <!-- other bit image -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please read our Help section on how to create an  MCVE
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.
You will get faster, better help from the community that way.

Comment: Do you want to follow all the bootstrap 'rules' for grids and not use any custom CSS? If so, then I don't think you can. But if you're willing to use some CSS style overrides than you can do anything CSS can do. (If that is the case, let us know so we can write up the CSS rules for you.) Also, is the overlapping absolute and static? Or can sizes and images change? Is this fluid and responsive grid that can automatically wrap columns depending on the viewport, or will it always be a minimum size?

Answer (score 0):

The columns themselves will NEVER overlap on the same plane. They can be placed above each other, but only the top-most will occupy the given pixels.

You can however, `overflow` the images, so they expand outside the space provided. See: https://jsfiddle.net/q9dn808p/1/ [terrible images used]

The question isn't 100% clear, so fixing as per noted in the comments would be advised. The other properties to solve your solution is `z-index`, in association with `position: fixed` or `position:absolute` to mark your larger image to a certain side of the page.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I meant and needed. Did not know anything about jsfiddle, that makes it a lot easier to make a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them overlay giving a margin value less than 0.

```
#left-picture{
  margin-right: -50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q9dn808p/2/

Is this what you are looking for?